# Where are the docs and api reference for Python's Bullet-for-Ursina lib?

Tags: python, ursina-engine

Where can I find the docs the and api reference for [Bullet-for-Ursina](https://github.com/LooksForFuture/Bullet-for-ursina)?
I already searched things similar to "Python Bullet for Ursina docs" but with no success.

Comment: Since there is not much activity on that Github project, the last update more than one year ago, the chance is high that there is no documentation. Your best bet would be to contact the author over the email in the git account